# Attribute "column" must be declared for element type "one-to-many"

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jar

i would like to create a dynamique web project with hibernate 3.In this project i have 2 classes and relation with them. The first class is **Ecole** and this is the attributs

```
package essai1;
```

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Ecole {

```
private int id_ecole;
private String nom_ecole;

private Set<Etudiant> etudiants = new HashSet<>();

public Set<Etudiant> getEtudiants() {
    return etudiants;
}

public void setEtudiants(Set<Etudiant> etudiants) {
    this.etudiants = etudiants;
}

public int getId_ecole() {
    return id_ecole;
}

public void setId_ecole(int id_ecole) {
    this.id_ecole = id_ecole;
}

public String getNom_ecole() {
    return nom_ecole;
}

public void setNom_ecole(String nom_ecole) {
    this.nom_ecole = nom_ecole;
}

public Ecole() {
    super();
}}
```

the second class has this attributs

```
package essai1;
```

public class Etudiant {

```
private int id_etudiant;
private String nom_etudiant;
private String prenom_etudiant;

private Ecole ecole;

public int getId_etudiant() {
    return id_etudiant;
}

public void setId_etudiant(int id_etudiant) {
    this.id_etudiant = id_etudiant;
}

public String getNom_etudiant() {
    return nom_etudiant;
}

public void setNom_etudiant(String nom_etudiant) {
    this.nom_etudiant = nom_etudiant;
}

public String getPrenom_etudiant() {
    return prenom_etudiant;
}

public void setPrenom_etudiant(String prenom_etudiant) {
    this.prenom_etudiant = prenom_etudiant;
}

public Ecole getEcole() {
    return ecole;
}

public void setEcole(Ecole ecole) {
    this.ecole = ecole;
}

public Etudiant() {
    super();
}}
```

I have the folder of the mapping Ecole.hbm.xml through which i create this file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="essai1.Ecole" table="ECOLE">
        <id name="id_ecole" type="java.lang.Integer" column="id_ecole">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="nom_ecole" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="nom_ecole" />
        </property>
        <set name="etudiants" inverse="true" table="ETUDIANT" cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="id_ecole" not-null="true"></column>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="essai1.Etudiant" column="idEtudiant" />         
        </set>


        <!-- <bag name="etudiants" table="Etudiant" lazy="true" inverse="true" 
            cascade="all"> <key column="id_ecole" not-null="true" /> <one-to-many class="essai1.Etudiant"> 
            <column name="idEtudint" ></column> </one-to-many> </bag> -->

    </class>


</hibernate-mapping>
```

In this file i have the problem of the mapping between the class of Ecole and the class Etudiant in the ligne **one-to-many** that i can't to add the attribute column="idEtudiant" in this tag 
the file of hibernate.cfg.xml is here

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/essaihibernate</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <mapping resource="map/Ecole.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="map/Etudiant.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

the file of mapping of Etudiant.hbm.xml is clearly and it has no problem and this is the code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="essai1.Etudiant" table="Etudiant">
        <id name="idEtudiant" type="java.lang.Integer" column="idEtudiant">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="nomEtudiant" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="nomEtudiant" />
        </property>
        <property name="prenomEtudiant" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="prenomEtudiant" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="essai1.ecole">
            <column name="id_ecole" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

the file of the hibernateUtil.java is there also

```
    package util;

import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;

public class HibernateUtil {

    public static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static {
        try {
            // Création de la SessionFactory à partir de hibernate.cfg.xml
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("map/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    // public static final ThreadLocal session = new ThreadLocal();
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

the jars were download :

1. antlr-2.7.6.jar
2. asm-1.3.3.jar
3. cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar
4. jta.jar
5. commons-collections-3.2.jar
6. commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
7. dom4j-1.6.1.jar
8. ehcache-1.2.3.jar
9. hibernate3.jar
10. log4j.jar
11. mysql-connector-java-5.0.4-bin.jar

the database

```
create database essaihibernate; use essaihibernate; CREATE TABLE `essaihibernate`.`ECOLE` ( `id_ecole` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `nom_ecole` TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id_ecole`) );
```

and the second table Etudiant is there

```
CREATE TABLE `essaihibernate`.`ETUDIANT` ( `id_etudiant` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `nom_etudiant` TEXT NOT NULL, `prenom_etudiant` TEXT NOT NULL, `id_ecole` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id_etudiant`), CONSTRAINT `FK_ETUDIANT_1` FOREIGN KEY `FK_ETUDIANT_1` (`id_ecole`) REFERENCES `ecole` (`id_ecole`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT );
```

the document imposes this orders of this all instructions but i can to mapped in my database because i have a problem with the column in the file Ecole.hbm.xml at the ligne 17

```
<one-to-many class="essai1.Etudiant" column="idEtudiant" />
```

the erreur is **Attribute "column" must be declared for element type "one-to-many"**
What can I do? I am very disappointed. help me my friend I am waiting for you

Answer (score 0):

This, from the Etudiant class

```
private int id_etudiant;
private String nom_etudiant;
private String prenom_etudiant;
```

is not what you have defined in the corresponding xml file, Etudiant.hbm.xml

Comment: So it is that i defined in Etudiant.hbm.xml. because i was testing in the other main class and i added in the database

Comment: Changing `<id name="idEtudiant" type="java.lang.Integer" column="idEtudiant">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>` to `<id name="id_etudiant" type="java.lang.Integer" column="idEtudiant">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>` doesn't help?

Comment: thank you for your advice in this code but my main problem is the adding of column in the fil **Ecole.hbm.xml**  this ligne **<one-to-many class="essai1.Etudiant" column="idEtudiant" />**
I want to add the instance **column="idEtudiant"** 
the **Attribute "column" must be declared for element type "one-to-many".** where i will add the instance of idEtudiant

Comment: Are you sure that it is the xml files that are matched against each other? Doesn't the parser (or compiler) look at the underlying class (Etudiant.java) and complain that it has no member idEtudiant?